# Asp.net and itextsharp maxime pdf space

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using itextsharp in .net to generate a pdf with some database data and it's alot. what i would like is to maximize the space.[image] Rather than making a new page at the end of the page I would like it to continue on the right side of the page and then proceed to a new page. Is this possible to achieve?

**EDIT**

This is how I'm writing data

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in gvInventario.Rows)
 {
        PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row.Cells[0].Text, times));
        PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row.Cells[1].Text, times));
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row.Cells[2].Text, times));
        PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row.Cells[3].Text, times));
        table.AddCell(cell1);
        table.AddCell(cell2);
        table.AddCell(cell3);
        table.AddCell(cell4);
 }

 doc.Add(table);
```

i have search online for an example and i found these.

https://freecontent.manning.com/wp-content/uploads/wrapping-tables-in-columns.pdf

This one would be ideal but this is java and i can't find out where to find this addHeaderTable function.

Comment: If the code is writing the individual items, then I can not think why you could not do this. Have you tried anything? It would be a complete guess for anyone on how you are writing this data. Without some code to go by, speculation is all you may get, however to answer your question… _”Is this possible to achieve?”_ YES and it will depend on “how” you are writing the data to the pdf.

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: Thank you !! I managed to do it by following this example and changing som code! You saved me a lot of time!